# Is there a limit to how many weapons you can have?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

I have amassed quite a few weapons for fusing in Kid Icarus Uprising. Is there a limit to the amount of weapons you can have? Like will some of the weapons disappear if there is too many?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**

There is no limit to the number of weapons you can have. Players have reached count of 1000s or even 10,000 weapons, without loosing a single one.

However, it's better to look into weapon fusion than just going "gotta have 'em all" on the weapons ;)

Comment: Thanks. Hmm I wonder what happens when we run out of memory?